# uploade image to mysql data base failure

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

hey i have following codes:

[index.php](https://github.com/BanShee8/simple-online-library/blob/master/index.php)

[select.php](https://github.com/BanShee8/simple-online-library/blob/master/select.php)

and you can also find whole project in GitHub (simple-online-library)

which works fine and save bookname bookauthor bookpages in mysql database but its just save image name and image path in database i just want to move image in to new folder called images and try several ways but none of them works for me.

Comment: first you repair your connection `$connect = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);`

Comment: add `var_dump($file);` before `$query` too see what info you get

Comment: @Mario thanks for your answer, i fix my connection and i add var_dump but its show nothing at all,just the browser alert box shows a [error.](http://i.imgur.com/elCHWPs.png) line 3 : `$file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"]));`

Comment: Yea as i supose, you have an empty string because you didn't process $_FILES['images'] from **form** that don't exists. Read this and it will be understand to you http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php You need this `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">` to be able to upload file.

Comment: i update my codes and my question.

Answer (score 1):

Should be fixed as below

```
 <?php  
require_once("db.php");
$file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"]));
 $sql = "INSERT INTO test1(name, lastname, age , images) VALUES('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["lastname"]."', '".$_POST["age"]."', '".$file."')";  
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
 {  
  echo 'infos saved';  
 }  
 ?>
```

**UPDATE**

your AJAX script only sending filename, not the image. Correct JS should be similar to one below.

```
$.ajax({
url: "ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
{
     // do something ex. $('#loading').hide();
}
});
```

Comment: why to store temp name ? how he will get image later ?

Comment: @Mario uses file_get_contents to read file content, it should work

Comment: @Оzgur thanks for answer, i use tour codes and update mine but still nothing changes and nothing upload to images row in DB its just show this [error in browser alert box.](http://i.imgur.com/elCHWPs.png) line 3 : `$file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"]))‌​;`

Comment: @jackson in your html code I can't see <form> element... there is a tutorial for your case. you can just download and continue over it. https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

Comment: @Оzgur because i dont use form i POST data to DB by using java. thank you anyway.

Comment: @jackson you are using JS, but still you need HTML elements. Best regards

Comment: @Оzgur i upload my whole project to [GitHub](https://github.com/BanShee8/simple-online-library) (i want to make opensource free online library cms.)